# Function Pointer typedef Error

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, function-pointers

i defined my Function pointer with a typedef like

```
typedef void (*ThreadFunc)( void *);
```

my Class member method looks like :

```
 void start( ThreadFunc f, vector<void *> &jobs)
```

in my main program i wrote a function like :

```
 ThreadFunc runner( void *job )
 {
  printf("->> %p\n", job);
 };
```

and want to run the member function
so i tried:

```
r.start( runner, jobs);
```

the compiler says:

```
main.cc:27: Fehler: ungültige Umwandlung von »void (* (*)(void*))(void*)« in »void (*)(void*)«
main.cc:27: Fehler:   Argument 1 von »void Thread::start(void (*)(void*), std::vector<void*, std::allocator<void*> >&)« wird initialisiert
```

Hope someone could help me short :) greetz

Comment: Please run your compiler in an environment with an english language locale when you want to copy the error messages here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`runner` needs to be declared returning `void`, not returning `ThreadFunc` to match the signature for `start`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ThreadFunc runner( void *job )
```

isn't actually a `ThreadFunc`, but a *function returning a `ThreadFunc`*. The compiler is telling you basically that.

It should work if you declare the function as

```
void runner( void *job )
```

Comment: @Nawaz: I think he meant just meant the function returns `ThreadFunc` rather than being of type `*ThreadFunc`.